# Testing Scipy; get "No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils"

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to test my `scipy` install by installing `nose` and entering

```
import scipy
scipy.test('1','10')
```

I get some 200 errors but one of the more common is:

```
.... No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
```

I have `MS Virtual Studio 2009` installed (required for python 2.7)

Can anyone help me eliminate that error or tell my why I can't?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem for me :(

Comment: A potential solution is listed [here](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy/issues/63).

Answer (score 1):

You have to do 2 things to make it find the Visual Studio Compiler:

1. In your environment, set VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS__vvv__COMNTOOLS% where **vvv** is your installed version. See other related questions on stackoverflow about setup.py and vcvarsall.bat
2. Run python from a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt. VS includes a link for this in the start menu. It sets up all the environment variables you need to run the compilers and related tools from the command line.

Comment: By the way, that error message will still be displayed, but then distutils will correctly find the compiler.

Comment: No luck with neither.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution to this could be using the Anaconda Python distribution

It has most of the engineering and data analysis packages and automatically sets path of the C++ compiler. You can easily install numpy, scipy, matplotlib etc. using Anaconda. It will not show vcvarshall.bat as well as numpy.core.multiarray error for numpy

Comment: Good advice but I'm trying to install numpy for Pypy and this is not going to solve it in such cases. I know the OP was about Scipy so your answer is definitely valid.