# Python install package getting error with msvccompiler

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2008

I have already install python(x,y)2.7.6.1 in Windows7 64bit

and try to install a package "imreg" (from [here](https://github.com/pyimreg/python-register))

> python setup.py install

I am getting this error:

> no module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils trying from distutils customize msvccompiler

I have installed visual studio 2008 and Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7(from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266))

but I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing Scipy; get "No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619649/testing-scipy-get-no-module-named-msvccompiler-in-numpy-distutils-trying-from) - have you tried running from a VS command prompt?

Comment: According to the link for "imreg", you also need NumPy >= 1.5, SciPy >= 0.9, and py.test >= 2.0 installed.

Comment: I have tried the way "set VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS__110__COMNTOOLS%",but I still got the same problem.I am sure the version of NumPy >= 1.5, SciPy >= 0.9, and py.test >= 2.0 have been installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this question by this way:

MinGW with C++ Compiler installed.

in " C:\Python27\Lib\distutils"  create a file "distutils.cfg" and add these lines:

> [build]
>
> compiler=mingw32

the answer is from [How to use MinGW's gcc compiler when installing Python package using Pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297254/how-to-use-mingws-gcc-compiler-when-installing-python-package-using-pip)