# having problems installing pytables

Tags: python, numpy, pytables, numexpr

I'm trying to install pytable, but first i must install numpy and numexpr to my windows 7 machine, I tried to install numexpr-2.2.2 an this is what happen

```
Warning: Assuming default configuration (numexpr\tests/{setup_tests,setup}.py was not found)Appending numexpr.tests configuration to numexpr
Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'numexpr' to 'numexpr.tests')
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building extension "numexpr.interpreter" sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
writing numexpr.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to numexpr.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to numexpr.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'numexpr.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'numexpr\__config__.py'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'RELEASING.txt'
writing manifest file 'numexpr.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying build\src.win32-2.7\numexpr\__config__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\numexpr

running build_ext
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
building 'numexpr.interpreter' extension
compiling C sources
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

CAN SOMEONE HEEELLLP ME PLEASE, THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What C++ compiler do you have on your machine?  There can be compatibility issues depending on the compiler.  MinGW's compiler should work for most Python modules.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27416818/4451284) for how to configure a "distutils.cfg" file to specify the location of the compiler.  (You may also have to edit your system environment variable PATH so that Windows finds your compiler in the right place.)

Hopefully with MinGW and the proper distutils configuration you should be able to get your module installed.

Comment: I'm sure what I'm doing wrong but I install mingw compiler and created cfg file inside of the disutils folder and try to install numexpr again and this is what I got [code] 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Building msvcr library: "C:\Python27\libs\libmsvcr90.a" (from C:\Windows\winsxs\
x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr9
0.dll)
error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Are you trying to install from source, or using pip?
There are also binaries you could look into trying: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables , or if you would be content with a pre-bundled binary solution, https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/